# Installing or upgrading version of cURL

Tags: linux, curl, centos, centos6

I am trying to update curl package on Centos 6.6. Currently it is installed version 7.19. I created new repo file:

```
[CityFan]
name=City Fan Repo
baseurl=http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

And after that

```
yum clean all
```

And when I now run command to list all packages on selected repo:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="city-fan.org" list available | grep curl
40:curl.i686                                 7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
41:curl.x86_64                               7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
74:libcurl.i686                              7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
75:libcurl.x86_64                            7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
76:libcurl-devel.i686                        7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
77:libcurl-devel.x86_64                      7.47.1-4.0.cf.rhel6       city-fan.org
78:libcurl7112.i686                          7.11.2-25.cf.rhel6        city-fan.org
79:libcurl7112.x86_64                        7.11.2-25.cf.rhel6        city-fan.org
80:libcurl7155.i686                          7.15.5-17.cf.rhel6        city-fan.org
81:libcurl7155.x86_64                        7.15.5-17.cf.rhel6        city-fan.org
```

there is version 7.47.

However, I still don't have an option to install version 7.47 that is shown above. When I run `yum --showduplicates list curl | expand` I get this:

```
Loaded plugins: presto, priorities, security
3584 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
curl.x86_64                         7.19.7-46.el6                          @base
Available Packages
curl.x86_64                         7.19.7-46.el6                          base
```

Also, I tried running `sudo yum install curl-7.47.1-4.0`

```
Loaded plugins: presto, priorities, security
Setting up Install Process
3584 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package curl-7.47.1-4 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

still nothing. yum install curl upgrade won't to anything also. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `curl` is the name of the package you're trying to install.  What about `yum --disablerepo="*" --enable-repo="city-fan.org" install curl` ?  I'm not sure `city-fan.org` is the correct name.  Run `yum repolist` to confirm.

Comment: Just tried on another Vagrant Centos box, repo is found  under 'CityFan' name. However, I don't really know how to install anything from that repo.

Comment: Oh, sorry @drew010 I see now what I did, I didn't even specified curl in yum install. However, I tried running sudo yum install curl-7.47.1-4.0, I get the same thing, only the old version is available.

Comment: Does `yum --enablerepo=cityfan install curl` or `yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=cityfan install curl` (or using `cityfan.org` whichever is correct) not work here? (Though I would recommend **against** replacing the system curl package/library as that may not work as you expect since many things depend on it.)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. Nevermind, I gave up.